# Cannot connect to google talk using empathy/pidgin after upgrading

Tags: 10.10, empathy, pidgin, google-talk

I can't seem to be able to connect to google talk using either pidgin or empathy after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10 (fresh install).

I do not know why... empathy just writes "Connecting ..." forever and never connects. What can I do from there?

Google talk's web interface works just fine for me so I doubt it is a firewall issue.

EDIT: In fact sometimes it's able to connect (empathy), it just takes a LOOONG time (I'd say about 5 mins), longer than I am willing to wait. On the other hand, the web interface is able to connect in seconds.

Comment: Open empathy from the terminal, this might output some messages which could give clou a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this problem today. But it does connect, so this may actually be a bug in empathy/pidgin. Report it by typing this in a terminal:

> ubuntu-bug empathy

Replace empathy above with pidgin if you want to report a bug in pidgin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Add Google Talk account
2. Login ID: username@gmail.com
3. Password: ******
4. [x] Encryption required (TLS/SSL)
5. [x] Ignore SSL certificate errors
6. Resource:
7. Priority: 0
8. Server: talk.google.com
9. Port: 443
10. [x] Use old SSL

Comment: didn't work. i guess my network firewall must be interfering...

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the same problem today and after waste a couple of hours I found a solution and I posted it in my Blog:

http://rodrigoguarischi.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/fixing-empathy-bug-gtalk-contact-doesnt-appear/

I hope it helps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please make sure to mention you're linking to *your* blog. Also, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In the event your blog is down or unavailable the information will live on.